# Share data across classess

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm currently writing a program to read and parse ext2 filesystem C++. I split my program to a few classes, e.g. `Ext2` as the main class, `Superblock`, etc. I have some data that I'll retreive once and I want it to be avilable to all the classes, e.g. block size, etc. What is the best way to achieve data sharing among several classes in a program without using globals (which I know are notorious)?

One way that crossed my mind is to keep those data bits as members in the main Ext2 class, and then pass reference to that instance to each class that needs to access this information via getter methods. Is there better way?

Comment: That's a question of life-time. If the owner of the shared data out-lives all other objects, then it could be member for which a reference could be passed to others. Otherwise, I would consider a [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which allows shared ownership in an idiomatic way.

Comment: My impression is that the appropriateness of globals (and similar alternatives like singletons) should not be dismissed so quickly. A key factor to consider might be: will this data ever change after being retrieved? Global data that never changes is far less troublesome than data that changes at the drop of a hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a seperate struct containing this data, and make all data sharing classes point to the same instance of this struct (Do watch out for memory leaks though, and maybe consider [shared pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).

```
struct SharedData
{
    int someValue;
};

class Thing
{
public:
    SharedData *shared;
    void printData()
    {
        std::cout << shared->someValue << std::endl;
    }
};

class OtherThing
{
public:
    SharedData *shared;
    void changeData(int newValue)
    {
        shared->someValue = newValue;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SharedData s;
    s.someValue = 10;

    Thing a;
    OtherThing b;
    a.shared = &s;
    b.shared = &s;

    std::cout << s.someValue << std::endl;
    //prints 10;

    b.changeData(20);
    a.printData();
    //prints 20;
}
```